# unknown resource 0: Robolectric fails with ShareActionProvider when I upgrade to AppCompat

Tags: android, robolectric

The team I'm on is introducing AppCompat finally (hurrah) but our test suite fails since the upgrade.

When running the test suite from the command line I was getting an issue with some of the tests.

When running them individually from Android Studio they pass.

What I find interesting about the stack trace is that it has a reference to ShareActionProvider when we don't use the share icon at all in our toolbar.

Stack trace below:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: unknown resource 0
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getAndResolve(ShadowAssetManager.java:384)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getResourceValue(ShadowAssetManager.java:129)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1347)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:226)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:199)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider.onCreateActionView(ShareActionProvider.java:229)
    at android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider.onCreateActionView(ActionProvider.java:166)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:630)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:190)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:451)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1138)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:91)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:284)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1030)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1053)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:460)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add this line to our top level theme:

```
<item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_share</item>
```

Where `ic_share` is an icon we use for share.

For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/ic_share</item>
</style>
```